# How to get the %AppData% folder in C?

Tags: c, windows, appdata

As above, how do I get the AppData folder in Windows using C?

I know that for C# you use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [SHGetSpecialFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28VS.85%29.aspx) with a [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx) set to the desired folder (probably CSIDL_APPDATA or CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA).

You can also use the newer [SHGetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SHGetKnownFolderPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) functions.
There's also [SHGetKnownFolderIDList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762187%28VS.85%29.aspx) and if you like COM there's [IKnownFolder::GetPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761762%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Note that this function was superseded twice already. You might as well give the other two (including the current and recommended function).

Comment: @Joey - I had not realized that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If I recall correctly it should just be

```
#include <stdlib.h>
getenv("APPDATA");
```

Edit: Just double-checked, works fine!

Comment: Use the proper API instead, as environment variables on Windows are more a courtesy than a contract. They might not be present under all circumstances. However, `SHGetKnownFolderPath` *will* give you the path every time.

Comment: But SHGetKnownFolderPath might not be available either.  Tough cookies.

Comment: @Hans: SHGetSpecialFolderPath should be, though. Depending on the OS one targets.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `%APPDATA%` environment variable will probably work most of the time.  However, if you want to do this the official Windows way, you should use use the [`SHGetFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), passing the CSIDL value `CSIDL_APPDATA` or `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`, depending on your needs.

This is what the `Environment.GetFolderPath()` method is using in .NET.

**EDIT:** Joey correctly points out that this has been replaced by [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in Windows Vista.  News to me :-).

Answer (score 1):

You might use [these functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char *getenv( 
   const char *varname 
);
wchar_t *_wgetenv( 
   const wchar_t *varname 
);
```

Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *appData = getenv("AppData");
printf("%s\n", appData);
```

Comment: Use the proper API instead, as environment variables on Windows are more a courtesy than a contract. They might not be present under all circumstances. However, `SHGetKnownFolderPath` *will* give you the path every time.

Comment: It's useful to be able to override environment variables on a per-process basis. Why do you say they are "more a courtesy than a contract"? Is there some official or quasi-official documentation to this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Sample code from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha):

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,
   CSIDL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
   NULL,
   0,
   szPath)))
{
   PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("MySettings.xml"));
   HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(szPath, ...);
}
```

CSIDL_APPDATA = username\Application Data. In Window 10 is: username\AppData\Roaming

CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE = combine with CSIDL_ value to force folder creation in SHGetFolderPath()

You can also use:

CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = username\Local Settings\Application Data (non roaming)