# How to open a folder in %appdata% with C++?

Tags: c++, appdata

As you all know, the appdata folder is this

```
 C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Roaming
```

on windows 7

Since my application will be deployed on all kinds of Windows OSes i need to be able to get the folder 100% percent of the time.
The question is how do you do it in C++? Since i don't know the the exact Windows OS it could be XP,Vista or 7 and most importantly i don't know what the *Username* is.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964124/how-to-get-the-appdata-folder-in-c

Comment: That's in C, i am asking for C++

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For maximum compatibility with all versions of Windows, you can use the [`SHGetFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx).
It requires that you specify the [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx) value for the folder whose path you want to retrieve. For the application data folder, that would be `CSIDL_APPDATA`.

On Windows Vista and later, you should use the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx) instead, which requires that you specify the folder's [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457.aspx) value. Again, for the application data folder, the appropriate value is `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData`.

To use either of these functions from your C++ application, you'll need to include `shlobj.h`.

Comment: Which do you recommend?

Comment: @mfce: Uh, the first one is what you should use on versions of Windows prior to Vista (like Windows 2000 and XP). However, it has been deprecated as of Windows Vista, and new applications written for Vista and 7 should always use the second one. So it depends on which version of Windows the program is running on.

Comment: It's targeted for both.

Comment: @mcfe: Okay... Then you'll need an `if` statement. Determine which version of Windows the program is running under and call the appropriate function. You'll need to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` for `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, as it's not defined for versions prior to XP.

Answer (score 26):

You can try the following:

```
char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA");
```

This code reads the environment variable APPDATA (you can also see it when you type `SET` in a command window). It is set by Windows when your system starts.

It will return the path of the user's `appdata` as an absolute path, including *Username* and taking into account whichever OS version they're using.

Comment: For those who are curious, this won't work on XP since appdata isn't a recognized environment variable. programfiles will work, however.

Comment: with the years `getenv` got deprecated, and now it's recommended to use the safer `_dupenv_s`

Comment: `SHGetFolderPath` has a `CSIDL_APPDATA` option that works with XP FWIW, see other answers here...

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps fellow Googlers might find it interesting to have a look at std::filesystem.  For instance, let's assume the default temp directory location and AppData directory structure in Windows 10:

```
#include <filesystem>

auto path = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path()
    .parent_path()
    .parent_path();

path /= "Roaming";

if (!std::filesystem::exists(path))
    std::filesystem::create_directories(path);
```

In the case of OP, I am assuming this doesn't solve the problem. **I do want to raise a word of caution against doing the above in a situation that requires a 100% robust implementation, as system configurations can easily change and break the above.**

But perhaps new visitors to the question might find std::filesystem useful.  Chances are, you're going to want to manipulate the items in the directory if you're looking for it, and for this, std::filesystem can be your friend.

Comment: Note: `std::filesystem` is only available since C++17

Answer (score 10):

If someone is looking for a simple implementation, here's mine:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::filesystem::path path;
    PWSTR path_tmp;

    /* Attempt to get user's AppData folder
     *
     * Microsoft Docs:
     * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath
     * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid
     */
    auto get_folder_path_ret = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, nullptr, &path_tmp);

    /* Error check */
    if (get_folder_path_ret != S_OK) {
        CoTaskMemFree(path_tmp);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Convert the Windows path type to a C++ path */
    path = path_tmp;

    /* Free memory :) */
    CoTaskMemFree(path_tmp);

    std::cout << path << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this Code to reads the environment variable "APPDATA"
Include stdio.h file in beginning

```
char *pValue;
size_t len;
errno_t err = _dupenv_s(&pValue, &len, "APPDATA");
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dupenv-s-wdupenv-s?view=msvc-160

FYI: This function cannot be used with UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation for old C++ versions :

```
#include <shlobj.h>
// ...
wchar_t* localAppDataFolder;
if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, KF_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, &localAppDataFolder) != S_OK) {
    std::cerr << "problem getting appdata folder" << std::endl;
}
else std::wcout << L"folder found: " << localAppDataFolder << std::endl;
```