# system() command with spaces

Tags: c++, powershell

I'm trying to execute a PowerShell command via `system()` command, but encounter an exception because of the spaces in the string, I tried a few things but still got the same exception.

Code:

```cpp
system("powershell.exe -command Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/myEXE.exe -OutFile C:\\Program Files\\myEXE.exe");
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument 'Files\myEXE.exe'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/myEXE.exe -OutFile C:\Program File ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Quote the `OutFile`: `system("powershell.exe -command Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com/myEXE.exe -OutFile 'C:\\Program Files\\myEXE.exe'");`

Comment: That worked, Thanks!
I tried doing the same thing with system("'C:\\Program Files\\myEXE.exe'"); to start the exe but it separates "Program" and "Files", any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Windows can work with `PROGRA~1` to address `Program Files`. Therefore, `'C:\\PROGRA~1\\myEXE.exe'` should work

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with %appdata% but cant make it work, and similar shortcut for it?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964124/how-to-get-the-appdata-folder-in-c) points you in the right direction how you can resolve special paths (such as `%appdata%`) under windows. Also the proper way to run other programs (including powershell) on windows is to use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa).

Comment: I know this function and have used it before, but the return value of it makes it hard for me to combine with a system() string, and that's why I'm trying to use %appdata% directly :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(){
    std::cout << "trying system command" << std::endl;
    system("powershell.exe -command Invoke-WebRequest https://make.sure.valid.url.to.test.otherwise.will.fail.anyways -OutFile 'C:/Program` Files/myEXE.exe'");
}
```

The ` charachter should allow you to properly escape the space.

Comment: The powershell command already works with the solution suggested above, I tried your solution with my second command that doesn't work but it didn't even let me include the <bits/stdc++.h>... This is the command I need working:  system("'C:\\Program Files\\myEXE.exe'");